# Brightcove implementation + unrecognized selector in iOS

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector, brightcove

I am facing a strange issue while integrating Brightcove library (version 4.2.1) in my iOS app.

```
    -(void) setupForBrightcove{
NSString *playlistID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",self.playListID];
BCOVCatalogService *catalog = [[BCOVCatalogService alloc] initWithToken:VIDEO_TOKEN];

//Find Playlist
    [catalog findPlaylistWithPlaylistID:playlistID
                             parameters:nil
                             completion:^(BCOVPlaylist *playlist,
                                          NSDictionary *jsonResponse,
                                          NSError      *error) {
}];
```

}

I just ran this much piece of code with valid playlist ID and Video Token.

It is giving me following error:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM bcov_UTF8EncodedRequestParameterString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a40f910
```

The only dictionary over here is `jsonResponse`.

Can anyone help on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't add `-ObjC` to your "Other Linker Flags" in your Xcode project build settings. Be sure to follow the [installation steps](https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios#installation) exactly.

Comment: Hi @erik, I have added -ObjC into other linker flags, still the issue persists.

Comment: Hm, not sure what the problem is. This method (defined in https://github.com/brightcove/brightcove-player-sdk-ios/blob/master/Headers/NSDictionary%2BBCOVURLSupport.h ) is a category method declared in a file that contains only category methods, which means that if `-ObjC` is not specified in the build settings, the linker doesn't link in the method implementation, which results in the error you see. Try the `nm` tool to verify that this method is linked in. You can also ask on the official forum: http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-ios/forum/sdk.html